# Как записать значение поля textarea в переменную?

Tags: reactjs

Получаю данные через props и вывожу через textarea. После внесения изменений в поле textarea текст поля должен сохраниться в переменную и при нажатии кнопки сохранить передаться на сервер.

```html
<div className="Npost" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <textarea rows={1} onChange={this.handleChange} id="z">{this.props.headernews}</textarea>
                <textarea rows={1} onChange={this.handleChange} id="t">{this.props.textn}</textarea>
                <button onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>Сохранить</button>
            </div>
```

пытаюсь сохранить значение в переменную но не сохраняется ничего

```js
handleChange(event){
        this.setState({z: document.getElementById('z').value});
        this.setState({t: document.getElementById('t').value});
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `handleChange` приходит событие на изменение конкретного `textarea`, соответственно нужно обновлять только его изменения

```
handleChange(event){
        const {target: {id, value}} = event;
        this.setState({[id]: value});
    }
```

Comment: те вот this.setState({z: document.getElementById('z').value}); не работает?

Comment: честно говоря, я даже не понимаю, зачем искать элемент в доме, что бы достать его значение, если оно уже пришло в событии.. попробуйте вывести в лог - console.log('value', document.getElementById('z').value) в handleChange;

Comment: оно пришло но его надо изменить вот зачем его надо занова считать и передать

Comment: я вам написал как обновить это значение в локальный state

Comment: @ИванИванов Реакт работает с VirtualDOM, `document.getElementById` работает с нормальным DOM, поэтому в реакте правильно использовать метод, показанный @batman.